# Frames issue in Watir2.0.1?  (with DevKit installed!)

Tags: watir

I posted a few threads the other day on the Watir General Google Group, one of which detailed my difficulty using set_no_wait on a validated text field (link below); and was asked by Jarmo Pertman whether it was in a frame.  It is, and this concerns me a little; as sadly the site I'm testing is heavily frame-centric, with no immediate plans to modernise.

I recently migrated from an ageing Ruby1.8.6/Watir1.6.2 test environment to Ruby1.8.7-334/Watir2.0.1, and am now noticing more methods that are no longer working for me in frames.  For instance, click_no_wait on a button that presents a new window works perfectly fine in my old environment, but not in my new one.

This is a question to the Watir developer group.  Are no_wait methods known to be failing in frames in Watuir 2.0.1?  If so, are they being addressed?  If they're not, then I'll be forced to revert back to an archiac version of Ruby and Watir.  For many reasons, I don't want to do this.

(Environment: Ruby 1.8.7-334.  Watir 2.0.1.  XP Pro.  IE8)

http://groups.google.com/group/watir-general/browse_thread/thread/85a1a872d1e054dc

Comment: Something occured to me last night; I had installed DevKit, which was required to get the FastDebugger working in Netbeans 7.0.1.  After completely reinstalling Ruby1.8.7/Watir2.0.1 without DevKit, 
click_no_wait and set_no_wait now seems to be working for me. 

It means I'll have to use something else other than Netbeans to run my scripts, but at least my scripts work again. 


(https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) 


I hope this info helps someone else.

GJHmf

Comment: Post your comment as an answer and accept it, to make it explicit you have found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

from the comments:

Something occured to me last night; I had installed DevKit, which was required to get the FastDebugger working in Netbeans 7.0.1. After completely reinstalling Ruby1.8.7/Watir2.0.1 without DevKit, click_no_wait and set_no_wait now seems to be working for me. It means I'll have to use something else other than Netbeans to run my scripts, but at least my scripts work again. (github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit) I hope this info helps someone else. GJHmf – GJHmf Sep 1 at 10:19

(inserting this answer because:

1. the OP was requested to but had not done so within a months time.
2. it removes this from the list of 'un-answered' watir related
   questions

   )